# How to decorate a class method with arguments?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to understand how decorators work better, but I keep getting confused when it just doesn't work.

Heres what I have / want:

```
class myClass(object):

    @myDecorate("something")
    def test(self, arg1):
        print arg1

myInstance = myClass()
myInstance.test("i am arg1")
```

I will pass an argument to the decorator, which will not be sent to the method itself; instead be used to do something behind the scenes that the class method doesn't need to worry about. When I call the class method, I want it to send `self` and `arg1` through to it.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def myDecorate(something):
    # do work here
    def decorate(f):
        def _wrapper(self, arg1, myOtherArg):
            # do something with myOtherArg
            return f(self, arg1)
        return _wrapper
    return decorate
```